# R: How to order hourly measurements per day from early to later and add a number accoring to this order?

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have this dataframe part of a much larger one:

```
[7111,] 20100321  0.8000000  
[7112,] 20100321  0.1000000  
[7113,] 20100322  0.3000000  
[7114,] 20100324  0.4000000  
[7115,] 20100324  0.2000000  
[7116,] 20100325  0.4000000  
[7117,] 20100326  0.7000000  
[7118,] 20100327  0.4000000 
[7119,] 20100328  0.1000000  
[7120,] 20100328  0.9000000  
[7121,] 20100328  0.2000000   
[7122,] 20100329  0.7000000
```

The first column contains the date, and the second column the moment in time on that date a measurement was taken (e.g: 0.0 = 00:00 hours and 0.5 = 12:00 hours). As you can see some dates have more than one measurement.

This is what I want to do: 
I want to order the time data per date from low to high on its particular day and add a number according to this order (1 is the earliest measurement, after that 2...3 etc. To get something like this:

```
[7111,] 20100321  0.1000000    1  
[7112,] 20100321  0.8000000    2
[7113,] 20100322  0.3000000    1
[7114,] 20100324  0.2000000    1
[7115,] 20100324  0.4000000    2
[7116,] 20100325  0.4000000    1
[7117,] 20100326  0.7000000    2
[7118,] 20100327  0.4000000    1
[7119,] 20100328  0.1000000    1
[7120,] 20100328  0.2000000    2
[7121,] 20100328  0.9000000    3
[7122,] 20100329  0.7000000    1
```

Does anyone know how to do this? Help would be great!

Comment: have you looked at `?order`?  Something like `yourdata[order(yourdata[,1], yourdata[,2]),]`.  However, instead, I'd suggest converting your date and time columns to one of the datetime data types in R.

Comment: That's a matrix, not a data.frame.  data.frames must have rownames, which your object does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `order` your `data.frame` and then use `ave` to create the third column very quickly:

```
df <- df [ order( df$V1 , df$V2 ) , ]
df$ID <- ave( df$V2 , df$V1 , FUN = function(x) 1:length(x) )
#        V1  V2 ID
#2  20100321 0.1  1
#1  20100321 0.8  2
#3  20100322 0.3  1
#5  20100324 0.2  1
#4  20100324 0.4  2
#6  20100325 0.4  1
#7  20100326 0.7  1
#8  20100327 0.4  1
#9  20100328 0.1  1
#11 20100328 0.2  2
#10 20100328 0.9  3
#12 20100329 0.7  1
```

`ave` takes subsets of your dataframe and returns a vector for each subset from 1 to `nrow(x)` where `x` is the current subset. It returns them as one long vector which we attach to the `data.frame` and then sort by the date column `V1` in my example and then the `ID` column.

Comment: I think you have to `order` first to meet the OPs requirements

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ddply` in the `plyr` package:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(ddply(x,c("date","time"),identity),"date",transform,order=seq_along(date))
       date time order
1  20100321  0.1     1
2  20100321  0.8     2
3  20100322  0.3     1
4  20100324  0.2     1
5  20100324  0.4     2
6  20100325  0.4     1
7  20100326  0.7     1
8  20100327  0.4     1
9  20100328  0.1     1
10 20100328  0.2     2
11 20100328  0.9     3
12 20100329  0.7     1
```

You will note that I call `ddply` twice: once to order the initial output on the 2 variables (`order` could have been used here instead), and a second time to transform it by adding order variable (which depends only upon 1 varaible, `date`).